# best "macro way" to repeat C# lines

Tags: c#, macros

In a C# program, I have an error check that gets repeated a lot:

```
try 
{
  File.Move(searchfolder + question1 +"_"+ filestring +".txt", 
            searchfolder + question1 +".txt");
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  File.AppendAllText(adminfolder + question1 +"_l.txt", "!"); 
  side.Value = Convert.ToString(ex) + "[Check-In error at "
                               + Convert.ToString(MYLINE) +"] "+ side.Value;
}
```

MYLINE is some number, and MYLINE is the only thing that changes across my program.

So a normal C++ #define macro would make this much simpler to work with (I would just write the full "#define CHECKIN(MYLINE) ..." once at the top of the program).

How would a pro deal with this in C#?

Comment: Can you clarify more, is it the whole try catch block that stays the same, just the catch, or just the string template of the exception?

Comment: I do hope you don't normally format your code like that. It was unreadable.

Comment: You need to look into *String.Format()* and *StringBuilder*

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but i wouldn't use a macro for that in C++ either.

Comment: Per decylone's suggestion you should change that last line to `side.Value = String.Format("{0}[Check-In error at {1}] {2}", ex, MYLINE, side.Value);`

Comment: BTW, Nice exception handling... what if File.AppendAllText will throw ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...and MYLINE is the only thing that changes across my program. So a normal C++ #define macro would make this much simpler to work with

Well, perhaps, but since C# doesn't have a concept of macros... just use a method:

```
static class FileMover
{
    public static void MoveMyFile(string myline)
    {
        // your existing code here
    }
}
```

On a side note, there is glaring problem in your code.  In your `catch` block you call `File.AppendAllText()`... which, of course, can throw an exception as well.  You need to account for that.

Comment: But, I think I then need my other variables (searchfolder, question1, and filestring) at the FileMover class' scope (global, right?) so doesn't this then force me to make these variables global?  The C++ macros are nice because they avoid the scope issues.

Comment: @bobuhito: You can simply pass those in as arguments as well.  Whatever macros in C and C++ may be, they don't exist in C#.  You need to stick to the rules of the language you're using.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a bad decision on the part of the C# creators.  My code gets about 4x longer than the C++ method (and it's also conceptually worse in my opinion).  I'll reluctantly mark your answer as the best if nobody can beat it...but, I honestly now think a pro would either leave C# or use some self-built pre-processor with macro syntax as a wrapper into C#.

Comment: @bobuhito: Well, you're of course entitled to your opinion, but I've been bitten enough by the pre-processor to not miss it in C#.  Hard to debug, strange runtime/compile time errors... I'd be fine with free functions, but no need for macros IMO.